# How to merge master branch to my current branch

Tags: git, github

I am new to GitHub. I have a 'master' branch and my branch is called 'noisy'. The master branch has new important changes I need to merge now, but I have code in progress and haven't push to my branch 'noisy' yet. What commands can keep my current codes written in 'noisy' and also merge the important changes on 'master' branch? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git stash`

As per the example on the [Git-Stash Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

> When you are in the middle of something, you learn that there are upstream changes that are possibly relevant to what you are doing. When your local changes do not conflict with the changes in the upstream, a simple git pull will let you move forward.
>
> However, there are cases in which your local changes do conflict with the upstream changes, and git pull refuses to overwrite your changes. In such a case, you can stash your changes away, perform a pull, and then unstash, like this:

```
$ git pull
 ...
file foobar not up to date, cannot merge.
$ git stash
$ git pull
$ git stash pop
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't committed your changes to 'noisy' branch then they won't go to master branch when you merge 'noisy' branch to master branch. To get an idea about git merge refer [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep your git tree cleaner and nicer i would recommend the following steps:

```
Git checkout noisy
Git fetch.
Git stash.
Git checkout master
Git reset --hard origin/master
Git checkout noisy
Git rebase master
Git stash pop
```

It's a bit longer but it's a good practice to make sure your git tree is cleaner.